# Añadir fila de campos input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Hola me gustaría que al hacer click en un botón por ejemplo me apareciesen tantas de campos como clicks de al boton +

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que deberías hacer es crear una **variable:any[] = []** y en el evento  de **(click)** y luego hacerle push ejemplo:

components.ts

crear variable:

```
public subPeriodos:any[] = [];
```

evento click

```
public addElemnt(){
    this.subPeriodos.push({
      "descripcion":"",
      "fechainicio":"",
      "fechafin":"",
      "estadovisible":1,
      "estadoactivo": 0
    });
  }
```

en tu html seria de esta forma:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let d of subPeriodos;let i = index">
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td><a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block" (click)="removeTemp(i)"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="d.descripcion"></td>
      <td>
          <input type="date" class="form-control has-feedback-left" [ngModel]="d.fechainicio | dateInBootstrap" >
      </td>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control has-feedback-left" [ngModel]="d.fechafin | dateInBootstrap" >
      </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```